# Colour mappings in R Plotly for geographical data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-sf

I have a shapefile of the UK that I'm trying to plot in Plotly as part of a Shiny app. Each region has a value attributed to it, between 0 and 5, but may also be NA. How do I get the NA values to appear in grey (for example), and the rest of the plot to follow a gradient?

`data()` in the following is a reactive Shiny object which reads the shapefile joined to my data dependent on a user input.

The Plotly code is as follows:

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(data(), 
                                     split = ~region,
                                     color = ~value,
                                     span = I(1),
                                     showlegend = FALSE,
                                     colors = colorRampPalette(c("green","yellow","red"))(50),
                                     alpha = 1
                                     )
                           })
```

Currently, the maps plot fine, but when there are `NA` values, these regions appear as white with colour borders and I get a load of

```
Warning: line.color doesnt (yet) support data arrays
Warning: Only one fillcolor per trace allowed
```

I have tried a few things:

1. Passing a custom `colorscale` into the `fillcolor` argument, but this did not do anything and just defaulted back to the standard `colorscale`
2. Setting all `NAs` to be -1, then doing something like

```
colors = c(colorRampPalette(c("#c3c3c3", "c3c3c3"))(9),
           colorRampPalette(c("#c3c3c3", "green"))(2)
           colorRampPalette(c("green","yellow","red"))(49))
```

to segment the colors. This appears fine on the actual colorbar, but encounters issues when there are no `NA` values, since then values near to 0 get mapped into the grey region of the colorscale.

Using `ggplot` and `ggplotly` is not an option as the data is too large.

Any ideas? Ideally `plotly` would have an `nacolour` argument similar to that in `ggplot`, but I can't seem to find anything like that... thanks in advance!